# http://www redirects to different domain

Tags: apache-http-server, redirection

background: I had 2 websites one was using apache and another one was using node.js. It wasn't set up properly and now I removed the apache website and apache itself.

problem: now `http://www.1website.com` redirects to `https://2website.com` even though I don't own the domain anymore and the apache configuration is removed.
If you write `https://www or non-www`,  `http://non-www` then it works correct and redirects to `https://non-www`

Comment: Was it a 301 redirect? (Ie permenant). If so your browser might be caching it? Try in-private mode/ different browser or clearing your cache.

Comment: This sounds like more a `DNS`, and/or (web) *browser* problem. Does this also happen on *other* computers/smartphones attempting to connect to those host(s)?

Comment: Yes! It was a 301 redirect and it works properly (doesn't redirect to old domain) on other devices apparently. Thank you guys!